# How do I replace text that's in a specific location of a file with text located in another file with a bash script?

Tags: bash, sed, scripting

So let's say I have a text file, *filetobechanged.txt*:

```
3.141592       pi
6.626068       planck

# Like this and like that and like this
..1     kd6-officer kd6-officer
us..0 kd6-3.7
us00..0 kd6-3.8
us00..0 kd6-3.9
us00..0 kd6-3.1
```

And I have a second file, *subfile.txt*:

```
subtext
```

I want to change the word in column two, line two, of *filetobechanged.txt* with the word in *subfile.txt*; the word in *subfile.txt* won't always be `subtext`; the word in *filetobechanged.txt* won't always be `planck` . It'd be best to presume that both words in both files will ***always*** be completely different words.

Comment: Have you got this backwards, you want to update `filetobechanged.txt` with the contents of `subtext`? You say you want the substition to be based on where the word is located, so does this mean you want to change the second word on the second line regardless of what the word is? I find your question very confusing!

Comment: Yes, I want to change the word in column two, line two, of `filetobechanged.txt` with the word in `subfile.txt` ; the word in `subfile.txt` won't always be `subtext` ; the word in `filetobechanged.txt` won't always be `planck` .   

Sorry for my confusion.

Comment: Easy given a reasonable problem statement :-) Since you have already accepted an answer I will not post mine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change the non-blank characters before the end of the line in line 2, you could use

```
sed -i'' -e '2{s/[^[:blank:]]*$/'"$(cat subfile.txt)"'/;}' filetobechanged.txt
```

The `-i''` option edits the file in-place (GNU/BSD sed). Your word in `subfile.txt` may not contain any `/` characters or you would have to
replace the `/`'s in the command with a character not present in word (e.g. `@` or `,`).

Comment: Nice! That did it! Much appreciated!

Comment: Ha! I just ran into that issue with trying to replace the last line in a file using `sed -i '4s/.*/replacement-line/' file.txt` ...  but the replacement line is `/usr/bin/macchanger -r "$IFACE"` ... and I'm confused.

Comment: You need a different separator for the replacement like `sed -i'' -e '4{s@.*@'"$(cat subfile.txt)"'@;}'`.

Comment: ooOOOoooh! I get it! NEAT! =D

Comment: So, in `sed -i'' -e '2{s/[^[:blank:]]*$/'"$(cat subfile.txt)"'/;}' filetobechanged.txt`, `*$` directs it to the last word on line two. And.. if you wanted to do the first word of the line, you could do something like, `w*`... for example, you have a line in dog.txt that reads `untied dyslexic church of dog`, you'd do something like, `sed 's/\w*//' dog.txt`, to get ` dyslexic church of dog`. But how do you point to a word that's not the first or last, without using the word, itself, in the command?

Comment: To match the n-th occurrence, add `n` to the end of the substitution. `sed 's/\w*/xx/2'` would replace `dyslexic` with `xx`.
Or you can use groups `\(...\)` and backreferences `\n` where `n` is the number of the group, i.e. `sed 's/\w* \(\w*\)$/xx \1/'` replaces `of` with `xx` and the last word `dog` is reinserted with `\1` (the first group).

Comment: Gotcha. I have one more that I'm really struggling with that's very similar to what I was trying to do in my original post. I have a script, changemac, has the line `ExecStart=/usr/bin/macchanger -m 68:a3:c4:17:24:5f %I` . I'm trying to swap the mac address with the mac address located in another file, mac.txt. Trying to piece the puzzle together, i got as far as `sed 's/\w*/xx/8'` ... then realized that each colon separates the mac as if it's 6 different... words? or groups? So.. would you use groups like you'd used in your example to cut out the mac and everything after?

Comment: You could do `sed 's/ [0-9a-f:]\+/ xx/'` or more explicit `sed -E 's/([0-9a-f]{2}:){5}[0-9a-f]{2}/xx/'` with one group (but no backreference). Ask a new question if you need more regex tricks ;)

Comment: Haha! Will do. I know I'll have more. Thank you,  sir!

Comment: In addition to failing when subfile contains whatever delimiter the sed command is using, it'd also fail if it contains anything that looks like a backreference, e.g. `&` or `\1`.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't care about preserving white space between fields, this will work using any awk in any shell on every UNIX box and given any characters in either input file since it's simply doing a literal string assignment:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{new=$0; next} NR==2{$2=new} 1' subfile.txt filetobechanged.txt
```

if you do care then:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{new=$0; next} NR==2{sub(/[^[:space:]]+$/,""); $0=$0 new} 1' subfile.txt filetobechanged.txt
```

To replace the Xth word on the Yth line using GNU awk for the 3rd arg to match():

```
awk -v x=5 -v y=3 '
    NR==FNR { new=$0; next }
    FNR==y {
        match($0,"([[:space:]]*([^[:space:]]+[[:space:]]+){"x-1"})[^[:space:]]+(.*)",a)
        $0 = a[1] new a[3]
    }
1' subfile.txt filetobechanged.txt
```

e.g.:

```
$ cat subfile.txt
[[[ \1 ~`!@#$%^&*()_-+={[}]|\:;"'<,>.?/ ]]]

$ cat filetobechanged.txt
Now is the winter of our discontent
Made glorious summer by this sun of York;
And all the clouds that lour'd upon our house
In the deep bosom of the ocean buried.

$ awk -v x=5 -v y=3 '
    NR==FNR { new=$0; next }
    FNR==y {
        match($0,"([[:space:]]*([^[:space:]]+[[:space:]]+){"x-1"})[^[:space:]]+(.*)",a)
        $0 = a[1] new a[3]
    }
1' subfile.txt filetobechanged.txt
Now is the winter of our discontent
Made glorious summer by this sun of York;
And all the clouds [[[ \1 ~`!@#$%^&*()_-+={[}]|\:;"'<,>.?/ ]]] lour'd upon our house
In the deep bosom of the ocean buried.
```

If you want to do something similar with `sed` then see https://stackoverflow.com/q/29613304/1745001.